# Getting the left digit of number?

Tags: c

This may be very basic but i am looking for the simplest way to get the *left digit* of a number, and the *right digit* .

so `54` will give me two integers , `int a=5` , and `int b=4` .

Comment: @Curnelious Are you considering only two-digits numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
int x=54;
int left = x/10;
int right = x % 10;
```

Basic stuff

For iharob satisfaction

```
int left = (x/10) % 10;
```

Comment: this only works for 2 digits integer

Comment: @iharob - You are quick of the mark

Comment: @DimitriMockelyn - As specified in the question

Comment: I only see an example that has a 2 digit number, the question doesn't seems to specify this

Comment: sorry guys, i meant for 2 digits only, thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int x = 54;
int left;
int right;

right = (int)log10(x);
left  = x / (int)pow(10, right);
right = x % (int)pow(10, right);
```

notice that this works for any number of digits.

Comment: You could really cache that exponential into variable.

Comment: This is overkill using `pow` function

Comment: Ok, could you suggest a better solution?

Comment: I have - see my solution

Comment: That only works for 2 digits.

Comment: Recursion my dear friend will do it.

Comment: @EdHeal anyway the OP only wanted for 2 digits, so i suppose your answer is the right one.